# How can I configure VS Code to hide or delete cell outputs from Jupiter Nootbooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code 1.65.2 and it is very inconvenient for me to have the outputs of the cells of my Jupiter Notebook. I know that they can be removed one by one, but it is very cumbersome. Is there any configuration that hides these cells?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the outputs? If you run your code in the interactive window instead of the notebook, you can at least specify the max. amount of lines that will be printed, which will reduce the clutter.

Comment: when i load my jupiter notebook i see the outputs of the cell even when i did not executed it, tha's what i want to hide, becouse i want to see the output only when i execute the cels

Comment: Have you tried the Python interactive window? That one shows output only after you execute a cell.

Comment: not, becouse i want to use the jupiter notebook

Answer (score 2):

Click on it to hide the output.
[image: Click on it.]

Comment: i know that way, but i ask you, is there any way to do that automatic? Or config VS Code for that?

Comment: There is no way to automate it but you can clear all output with clear output all cells